# Getting Arrays to work with toupper

Tags: c++, arrays

For some reason I keep getting a error that says "toupper cannot be used as a function". But to my undersatnding toupper is a global function that converts lowercase chars to uppercase.

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>              
#include <string>

using namespace std;                

int main ()

{


  string input;
  string output;
  int toupper;

  cout<<"Enter a String of Charchters to be Capitalized : ";
  cin>>input;
  string arrayinput[20]= input;
  output = toupper(arrayinput);
  cout<<"\n\n\n"<<output<<"\n\n\n";



cout<<"Press <Enter> to Exit";
cin.ignore();
cin.get();      
return 0;                        
}
```

Comment: what does ` string arrayinput[20]= input` supposed to do?

Comment: take the input and make it into a array

Comment: @kd7vdb: That's not how it works. You can't just take a `std::string` and "make it into a array".

Comment: so would it be easier to take and make some sort of a input and make it into a array of chars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've created a local variable called `int toupper` - rename that one to something else.

Edit to add:
There are more problems than just this.  `input` is a string; you want to iterate through the length of that string and get `char*` at each position using `string::at(i)`.  Then use `atoi` to convert the char to an int, which is the type that `toupper` takes as an argument.

Comment: I removed the toupper variable and now I get a error of " invalid conversion from `std::string*' to `int' " does to upper have to be a integer?

Comment: @kd7vdb , no, just rename/remove the toupper variable. It gives you error because the variable has the same name with the function itself.

Comment: As far as I can tell, that's because you are passing the array (more specifically a pointer to the first element of the array) of strings to the function, you need to pass an actual element of the array, e.g. arrayinput[5]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it on an array of strings, then after fixing the variable name issue, use `std::transform` in a loop:

```
for (auto& str : arrayinput)
    std::transform(std::begin(str), std::end(str), std::begin(str), ::toupper);
```

Or if you don't have range-based for, you can use `for_each`:

```
std::for_each(std::begin(arrayinput), std::end(arrayinput), [](string& str) {
    std::transform(std::begin(str), std::end(str), std::begin(str), ::toupper);
});
```

Comment: Above I described how to convert your `string` to the data types used by `toupper` but if you can just stick with `string`, like here, that would be preferred.

Comment: @tmpearce no, `toupper` returns the ASCII code of the character, so you don't need to convert back or forth. And using `itoa` is for converting a number like `5` to the string `"5"`, which is not useful for this case.

Comment: ahhh right you are.  (I don't use itoa or atoi - go strings!)

Answer (score 0):

You have caused an ambiguity by declaring a variable with the same name as the function. As has already been stated, simply change the name of the variable, and that should resolve it.